# how to re-enable trackpad accidentally disabled it using third party software(Jupiter)

Tags: 12.04, mouse, trackpad

Im an ubuntu noob, I accidentally disabled my trackpad using the Jupiter power management software, but cant seem to be able to re-enable it. Tried rebooting the system to no avail. Any ideas on how to re-enable the trackpad would be useful.

Comment: You mean touchpad, on a laptop? Have you tried plugging in a (USB-)mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found out that lucky for us Jupiter uses a single script to do it.
Terminal time:

Enter the following script, (which will execute the script that runs when you click on enable/disable touchpad.

```
sudo /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/touchpad
```